# Very wide denormalized data (around 40000 columns). Which database to use?

Tags: database, postgresql, denormalization

I have a very specific problem. I have data with around 40000 columns. The data is denormalized because processing real time would take a lot.

Postgresql has a limitation on column numbers 1600. Can anybody suggest me a database which doesn't have this limitation?

Or if not a database, the method how very wide data can be stored?

The partitioning to smaller tables proved to be tedious task because joining them when a specific query is executed with specific filters can be really messy. I have tried that already.

Thanks!

Edit:

census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/data.html This is the dataset. 
Example table:

Nr. of people in some street:

Columns: Number of people, number of people age <18, number of people age<22, number of people age 22<30 etc.

And these combinations get higher and higher. Include race, gender, nationality etc. There are your 40000 columns. And these columns cannot be calculated on the fly. It needs to be precalculated and stored for faster reading – Forsythe 15 mins ago

Comment: I'm very curious on how adding lines with 40000 columns can be faster than normalized data using correct SQL joins and queries ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the table? Selects? Inserts? Updates? Whatever info? Did you try optimizing your queries yet?

Comment: Are you really sure all 40k columns should belong in one table?

Comment: 40000 columns? seriously? Very interested to know what this data represents. That should give a clue where it is going wrong.

Comment: @Martin Because column data is generated based on some formulas. Running these formulas to generate a new column would take a lot. So the data is precalculated and put into the table so it can be fetched fast.

Comment: @JakubKania Yes I am sure.

Comment: @PeeHaa Mostly Selects. The query is not a problem. The problem is that I need an efficent way to store data with 40000 columns into a database, without partitioning the data into smaller tables, and then joining them upon request.

Comment: Use a `hstore` column (a key/value store)

Comment: Well there is no way around that I know of, the column limitation is something you cannot break... So if you could give an example we might understand better and provide you with a headstart for a solution

Comment: https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/data.html

This is the dataset.

Table: Nr. of people in some street:

Columns:
Number of people, number of people age <18, number of people age<22, number of people age 22<30 etc. 

And these combinations get higher and higher. Include race, gender, nationality etc. There are your 40000 columns. And these columns cannot be calculated on the fly. It needs to be precalculated and stored for faster reading

Comment: So your problem is really that you are unable to write a proper dynamic query to query multiple tables? Don't cram so many columns in one table just because writing a SELECT was messy, you're better of without a RDBMS if you just want to treat it as one big table.

Comment: @JakubKania thats why I am posting this question. What is the best way to store such table. Look at my comment above.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't properly normalize that data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Normalization would give me more tables. I don't want more tables. I have this one table which I want to store. There must be a way to do it (doesn't have to be Postgres)

Comment: how do you remember the name of each column? It has no meaning you cannot get programmatically none column. Each time I see somebody the uses instructions that the simplest database, such SQLite cannot accept, I think it is structuring very very wrong his database. The special instructions are usefull with recursive datasets or special data, where SQLite cannot do nothing, if you do not want insert by your self. But an anagraphic dataset is the first example done in the first hour of SQL lesson.  This must be done with RDBMS

Comment: Why not use key->value pairs? 
Street is one street in one table, and all the columns in your dataset (age<22, age<24, and so forth) as a separate table with the columns "key" and "value" pointing to street?
Or even better, the tables "Street" and "Keys", and then a M-M table "values" that connect them. Then you can reuse and search very easily.

Simple and easy, requires minimal amounts of tables and doesn't break PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3):

All databases that I can readily think of have limits in the low thousands (at least SQL Server, MS Access, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, Teradata, and DB2). You might have better luck with columnar databases but these are rather specialized.

This leaves you with various options:

- You can use key-value pairs for the data. However, if the data is dense, then you might have very large data.
- You can use other data structures, such as JSON, XML, arrays (in Postgres), or BLOBs (binary large objects).
- You can use NOSQL technologies for storing the data.
- You can use statistics tools, such as R, SAS, and SPSS.

Ultimately, the question of how you want to store the data depends on what you want to do with it. For instance, if you have a system that has lots of relational data and functionality but has time-series data, then you can store the timeseries in its own table (one row per whatever and per time unit) or you might store the series as a BLOB because you are returning it to the application for further processing.

Comment: Also, it's possible to group columns together into several tables and join them accordingly. I would assume not all queries will need all 40k columns. This will also help to better cache hot data.

Comment: In Postgres I would probably use a `hstore` for this.

Comment: The data will mostly be used for reading, but with very specific constraints. Like for example, I would require to run a function on columns 1, 56, 10000, and 29999. Or even run a subquery. But in order to run that function (or subquery), I would have to have that table stored in a proper way. Postgres is currently giving me a headache. Because I have to split that big table into smaller ones ,and then join them upon some query (the user still "sees" the big table). E.g. the user sends a query for a big table, I have to parse that and get the data from all table chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm getting this wrong, but there seem to be a problem of understanding and data sotring here...

You say you want to display columns that say Number of People, people aged under 18, between 18 and 21... But this is not a propert way to store the data...

The REAL data here is the age of everybody, their gender... Then all the other columns are just calculated...

Then your query needs to be parametrized so you can select properly.

Example using PHP and MySQL :

```
//These vars come from user input
$ageMin = 18;
$ageMax = 21;
$gender = "male";

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE 
          Age >= {$ageMin} AND
          Age <= {$ageMax} AND
          Gender = '{$gender}' ... "
```

And if you say it cannot be precalculated, then store those result in a table as rows :

```
Table Calculated
  IDCalculation (INTEGER)
  Name (CHAR(30))
  Criteria
  Result
```

So you just transform your 40000 columns into rows